# How to get sum of int and 0 as missing with date in sql query?

Tags: postgresql, date, count, sum, sql-order-by

I have the following query and I would like to add all the views of a specific date and if there is no view, I would like to get date and sum as 0 as shown below.

```
SELECT SUM("videoView"."views"), "videoView"."startDate"::timestamp::date
FROM "videoView" 
WHERE "videoView"."videoId" =23 
AND "videoView"."views"
BETWEEN = '2021/11/25' AND '2021/11/28'
GROUP BY "videoView"."startDate"::timestamp::date
```

The result I want is:

```
sum     date
3       2021/11/25
0       2021/11/26
0       2021/11/27
4       2021/11/28
```

The result i am getting is

```
sum      date 
3        2021/11/25
4        2021/11/28
```

Comment: Pls. add DDL and data sample

Answer (score 1):

You need a *calendar* table here which holds all the dates which you want to appear in the report.  The need for this table is that your current data set may be entirely missing certain dates for which there simply isn't any data.  Consider:

```sql
WITH dates AS (
    SELECT '2021-11-25'::date AS dt UNION ALL
    SELECT '2021-11-26'::date UNION ALL
    SELECT '2021-11-27'::date UNION ALL
    SELECT '2021-11-28'::date
)

SELECT d.dt, COALESCE(SUM(v.views), 0) AS numViews
FROM dates d
LEFT JOIN videoView v
    ON v.startDate = d.dt AND
       v.videoId = 23
WHERE
    d.dt BETWEEN '2021-11-25'::date AND '2021-11-28'::date
GROUP BY d.dt
ORDER BY d.dt;
```

Comment: Would be probably be better to use `generate_series` to generate dates.

Comment: @hvester It would `definitely` be better to use `generate_series`.  I only used a CTE for transparency in the answer.